# Media queries css for more than 800 width devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the size screen from desktop to mobile in Visual Studio Code. The question is: modify the CSS by using media queries, so if the viewport is more than 800px it should display like this:

[image]

and if less than 800px it should display like this:

[image]

That's how I did it, but I guess it's wrong:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)


{

}
#container {


    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
   
}
#header {


    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:rgb(101, 161, 109);
    
    
    }
    
    
    #sidebar {
    
    
        width: 20%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: rgb(251, 127, 255);
        float:left;
    }
    
    
    #main {
    
    
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: brown;
    float: left;
    
    
    
    
    }
    #footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color:aqua;
        float:left;
    }

@media screen and (min-width : 600px) {
    


}
    
    #container {
    
    
        width: 100%;
        margin:auto;
       
    }
    #header {
    
    
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color:rgb(101, 161, 109);
        
        
        }
        
        
        #sidebar {
        
        
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: rgb(251, 127, 255);
            float:left;
        }
        
        
        #main {
        
        
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: brown;
        float: left;
        
        
        
        
        }
        #footer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color:aqua;
            float:left;
        }
```

I tried to adjust the desktop screen size to mobile in Visual Studio Code using Media Queries, but the code doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: *I tried to adjust the desktop screen size to mobile in Visual Studio Code using Media Quarries, but the code doesn't seem to be working.*
The media queries don't change the viewport, they only update sizes based on the viewport

Comment: Also, you said larger than 800px but in the code, the media query suggests you mean 600px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media query code is outside the media query declaration. Correctly it should be like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  #header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgb(101, 161, 109);
  }
  #sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(251, 127, 255);
    float: left;
  }
  #main {
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: brown;
    float: left;
  }
  #footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  #header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgb(101, 161, 109);
  }
  #sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(251, 127, 255);
    float: left;
  }
  #main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: brown;
    float: left;
  }
  #footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For media queries, your css has to be between the `{}`s like this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width : 600px) {
    #container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
   
    }
    /* Rest of your css */
}
```

Plus, css that is the same across viewpoints shouldn't be repeated in each media queries, for example, as the above code is in both media queries, you can just move it out of the media queries into the main css block.